# Use circular-menu.js inside Angular project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

There is already an unsolved topic for the same question/problem but my got deleted.

Basically trying to integrate this: https://github.com/yandongCoder/circular-menu to my angular project but so far no luck.
What I did so far:

- after npm installation of it:
- included both, .js and .css in angular.json
- `declare const CMenu: any` in my app.component.ts due to no no type declaration available
- included the `menu = CMenu("#menu1").config....` part as showed here in the creators example: https://jsfiddle.net/yandongCoder/kL4j7xor/10/
- put the css part into the component's scss file

Result:
[Error in Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOn1V.png)

Maybe someone experienced here with a good advice on where the problem could be? Or even a solution for it? Would be also awesome and helpful to know for others i think. Anyway already a big thanks for reading this and your help.

Edit:
As soon as I comment-out the menu variable declaration my page is loading again (obviously the js not working then) without error. So, something is happening. Might be a format problem of the menu variable declaration? Try to post here also a stackblitz or so if i manage to get it there

Comment: Please, go thu [ask], [mre], [help], etc before posting

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.